# Trying to get withRouter to work with my Provider class

Tags: reactjs

Working on a sign up route in React using context API (Mongodb for backend is already set up and working good). Once the log in is successful, I want to redirect the url. It worked fine until I tried to set export using  `withRouter` to make use of `this.props.history`.

The provider class works with no issues BUT `this.props.history` is undefined when I export it this way:

`export class Provider extends Component {`

When I try exporting it with the code below, it throws an error - see below for error

**Provider Class**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';

const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class Provider extends Component {

  state = {
    firstName: null,
    lastName:null,
    emailAddress: null,
    password: null,
    signedIn: false,
  };

  logOut = () => {
    this.setState({ 
      firstName: null,
      signedIn: false
    });
  };

  userData = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value
    });
  };

  logIn = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/users`, {
      auth: {
        username: this.state.emailAddress,
        password: this.state.password
      }
    }).then(res => {
      this.setState({
        firstName: res.data.firstName,
        signedIn: true
      })
      this.props.history.push("/");
      console.log('successful')
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('unsuccessful')
      console.log(err)
    });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider value = {{
        firstName: this.state.firstName,
        signedIn: this.state.signedIn,
        actions: {
          signedIn: this.state.signedIn,
          logIn: this.logIn,
          logOut: this.logOut,
          userData: this.userData
        }
      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>

    )
  }
}
export default withRouter(Provider)
export const Consumer = AuthContext.Consumer
```

**APP.JS**

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider>
          <Header />
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path='/courses' render={() =>  <Redirect to='/' />}/>   
            <Route exact path='/' component={Courses} />
            <Route path='/courses/create' component={CreateCourse} />
            <Route exact path='/courses/:id' component={CourseDetail} />
            <Route path='/courses/:id/update' component={UpdateCourse} />
            <Route path='/signin' component={UserSignIn} />
            <Route path='/signup' component={UserSignUp} />
            <Route component = {PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
      </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  };
};
```

This is the browser error I get with the above code:
`Attempted import error: 'Provider' is not exported from './Components/Context'`

If I remove `export default withRouter(Provider)` and export with this line `export class Provider extends Component` it works fine! but I need access to this.props.history somehow.

Any suggestions to redirect the url? or how to properly export my Provider class using withRouter? Thank you so much

Comment: In your `app.js`, import `Provider` with another name and try to see what happens

Comment: How do you import Provider in `app.js`?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for pointing me in that direction. I was importing it as { Provider } I removed the curly braces and now it works fine.